# Can I make text overflow from the bottom up outside a box?

Tags: html, css

I made some boxes with css at 30px by 30px and I uses the border on one side to be an indicator of the location. When I overflow text out of the box, like 3-5 lines, it overflows to the bottom and right no problem. However, I may like to make the text overflow from the top instead, so that the color boarder may be on the bottom of the location.

Here are some css and a box example

```css
    .box {
   position:absolute;
   width:30px;
   height:30px;
   z-index:5;
    }
    .rb{
   border-right:blue solid 10px; 
   padding-right:12px;
   text-align:right;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="box-i2" class="box rb">1508V 1519D 1520D 1521D</div>
</body>
</html>
```

in HTML like this box will be right aligned with the boarder on the top right of the text, because the text overflows below.

For example, the vertical bars indicate the text is overflowed the bottom of the box and the boarder is on the right, at the top of the text:

```
1508V |
1519D |
1520D 
1521D
```

So I am wondering if I can only make the result of same html come out with text overflowing from the top instead.

Essentially having the result of like so:

```
1508V 
1519D 
1520D |
1521D |
```

Where vertical bars indicate the bottomed boarder as the text overflows the top of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it would be better to use a pseudo after element, see my code example below.

You can play with the width and height on the .box here - I've just updated it for the example purpose.

This solution will work in all modern browsers, and will work in IE8 and IE9 also.

```css
.box {
   position:relative; /* position relative, or absolute only if required */
   width: 68px; /* box width required, but not height */
   z-index:5;
}
.rb{
   padding-right: 12px;
   text-align:right;
}
.rb:after {
    content: ''; /* required to display element */
    background: blue;/* your border color */ 
    width: 10px; /* your desired width */
    height: 50%; /* half the .box height */
    position: absolute; /* absolute position */
    bottom: 0; /* position at the bottom */
    right: 0; /* position on the right */
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="box-i2" class="box rb">1508V 1519D 1520D 1521D</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. This has nothing to do with the position of the blue part...it's about the text overflow.

Comment: thank you.It seem like CSS don't just do what I want. But I think this is the one way to workaround, but ill have to make a new class for the rightboarderbottom boxes. like '.rbb' with 'rbb:after' since there are too many .rb boxes already. I might use various background image though it is what I sought to avoid.

Comment: I also note that fixing hight of the ebb:after is fine too. Not needed to be % but 30px is work good too match other boarder sides that have color. thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad my suggested solution has helped you

Answer (score 1):

Not directly using `overflow` but you can use flexbox to mimic the behaviour.

*Note however that the overflowed text will not impact on the positioning of the primary container. You have to leave enough space (margin) above the container for it to show.*

```css
.box {
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.rb {
  border: blue solid 1px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-i2" class="box rb">1508V 1519D 1520D 1521D</div>
```

Comment: Be careful using display: flex; as it won't work in older web browsers such as IE8 and IE9.

Comment: I don't worry about out of date browsers and, AFAIK, this is the only CSS method to achieve what the OP is **actually** asking for.

Comment: @Angel Politis - When you work for a company that gets millions of website hits, you unfortunately have to support a variety of browsers, because it's financially not viable to exclude them.